# How to get clicked element only in stencilJS when shadow is set to true

Tags: shadow-dom, stenciljs

I am getting a problem that when I am setting shadow as true in my component I am getting whole dom when any image(other element too) clicked instead of the element which is clicked.

How can I resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your code look like? Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the answer:

```
 @Listen('click')
  onHandleClickEvent(ev) {
    // This will give you the clicked element (composedPath()[0])
    console.log('===== 31 =====', ev.composedPath()[0]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the currentTarget property of the event arguments object which is passed to the event handler in order to get the element which was clicked. For example, look at the following code:

```js
import { Component, Prop } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Prop() first: string;
  @Prop() middle: string;
  @Prop() last: string;

  constructor() {
    this.imgClicked = this.imgClicked.bind(this);
  }

  format(): string {
    return (
      (this.first || '') +
      (this.middle ? ` ${this.middle}` : '') +
      (this.last ? ` ${this.last}` : '')
    );
  }

  imgClicked(evt) {
    console.log(evt.currentTarget);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello, World! I'm {this.format()}<img src="https://twitter.com/gilfink" onClick={this.imgClicked}/></div>;
  }
}
```

In the code, the onClick handler (which is the imgClicked function) will print the image element which was clicked to the console.

Comment: Thanks @Gil have you tested this code on IE, edge and firefox ?? I mean is currentTarget working on these browsers

Comment: @LalitKushwah, it works on IE, Edge and Firefox - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: I am writing the following code  and getting the whole selector instead of target element

Comment: @Listen('click')
  handleClickEvent (event) {
    console.log('============= 268 =============', event.currentTarget)

Comment: You aren't using the Listen decorator as expected. Listen decorator is used to listen on custom events which are emitted by a Stencil component using the EventEmitter class. In your case in order to wire the event listener you should put the wiring in the render function like I showed in my example.

Comment: But stencil document says Listen decorator supports the native events https://stenciljs.com/docs/events

Comment: It is. But when you wire handlers to event inside a component it's using JSX and component methods. In my example you can see an image tag with a `onClick={this.imgClicked}` event. The Listen decorator is used to indicate that a parent component is listening to events that his child components can emit.

Comment: @GilFink, 
Without shadow DOM we can get the clicked element with
@Listen()
handleClickEvent(e) {
   console.log(e.target)
}
Is it possible any way with shadowDOM?